# How to resolve "return 0 or return 1" within a for loop in open mp?

Tags: c, openmp

This is what I have done so far to resolve the `return 1;`, `return 0;`, it is actually a sudoku solver using backtracking algorithm, so I am trying to parallelize it, but I cant get the complete result. (correct me if my implementation is wrong)
what actually happen?
anybody can help?!

this is the site i refer to, i used to follow their way : http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2007/06/29/breaking-out-of-loops-in-openmp/#reply

```
int solver (int row, int col)
{
   int i;
   boolean flag = FALSE;
   if (outBoard[row][col] == 0)
   {
      #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
      #pragma omp parallel for //it works if i remove this line
      for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      {
         if (checkExist(row, col, i)) //if not, assign number i to the empty cell
            outBoard[row][col] = i;

         #pragma omp flush (flag)
         if (!flag)
         {
            if (row == 8 && col == 8)
            {
               //return 1;
               flag = TRUE;
               #pragma omp flush (flag)
            }
            else if (row == 8)
            {
               if (solver(0, col+1))
               {
                  //return 1;
                  flag = TRUE;
                  #pragma omp flush (flag)
               }
            }
            else if (solver(row+1, col))
            {
               //return 1;
               flag = TRUE;
               #pragma omp flush (flag)
            }
         }
      }


         if (flag) { return 1; }

         if (i == 10) 
         { 
            if (outBoard[row][col] !=  inBoardA[row][col]) 
            outBoard[row][col] = 0;
        return 0; 
          } 

     } 
     else 
      { 
        if (row == 8 && col == 8) 
         { 
        return 1; 
          } 
         else if (row == 8) 
         {    
            if (solver(0,col+1)) return 1; 
          } 
          else 
          { 
            if (solver(row+1,col)) return 1; 
           } 

     return 0;
    }
}
```

---

```
5 0 0 0 0 3 7 0 0
7 4 6 1 0 2 3 0 0
0 3 8 0 9 7 5 0 2
9 7 0 4 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 2 0 0 0 4 0 0
0 0 4 0 0 5 0 1 9
4 0 3 2 7 0 9 8 0
0 0 5 3 0 9 6 7 4
0 0 7 5 0 0 0 0 3
Sudoku solved :
5 2 9 8 0 3 7 4 1
7 4 6 1 5 2 3 9 0
1 3 8 0 9 7 5 6 2
9 7 0 4 1 0 2 3 6
0 1 2 9 6 0 4 5 8
3 6 4 7 8 5 0 1 9
4 0 3 2 7 6 9 8 5
2 8 5 3 0 9 6 7 4
6 9 7 5 4 8 1 2 3
```

The `//return 1;` is the original serial code, since `return` is not allowed in the `parallel for`, so I used `#pragma opm flush` to eliminate it, but the result is not complete, it still left few empty grids in the sudoku.

Thanks for answering :>

Comment: "i hope my code doesnt mess you up" No it doesn't, but your spelling and grammar is terrible.  Please at least try clean it up a bit so it's readable.

Comment: @Tony, forgive me for my poor english, i will improve it.I am happy if you could answer my question?

Comment: I don't have any experience with openmp, so can't help you. Sorry :(

Comment: Branching in a loop the way it is done in the article you refer to is a terrible idea. OpenMP is not designed for that. OpenMP is a data-parallel paradigm and should only be used for simple data-parallel algorithms. For anything more complicated there are other paradigms to be employed.

Comment: @Hristo, i changed the #pragma omp parallel for to #pragma omp parallel, it can get the correct result...i wonder why now...

Comment: Not all of your function code is presented. Besides, you have two nested parallel regions. You should really have only one line like `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)`. Also check that the solver works with OpenMP disabled.

Comment: @HristoIliev, actually i thinking to apply MPI, but i found it complicated, so i decided to use openmp.

Answer (score 0):

First, since `solver` is called recursively, it doubles the number of threads with each level of recursion. I don't think it's what you intended to do.
**Edit**: This is only true if nested parallelism is enabled with `omp_set_nested()`, and by default it is not. So only the first call of `solver` will fork.

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
#pragma omp parallel for
```

in your code tries to create one parallel region within another, and it will cause the loop that follows to execute twice, because outer `parallel` already created two threads. This should be replaced with

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
#pragma omp for
```

or equivalent `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)`.

Second, this code:

```
if (checkExist(row,col,i))//if not, assign number i to the empty cell
    outBoard[row][col] = i;
```

creates a race condition, with both threads writing different values to the same cell in parallel. You might want to create a separate copy of the board for each thread to work with.

Another code part,

```
if (outBoard[row][col] != inBoardA[row][col]) 
    outBoard[row][col] = 0;
```

seems to be outside the parallel region, but in nested calls to `solver` it's also executed in parallel in different threads created by the outer-most `solver`.

**Final(e)** (18.09) Anyway, even if you manage to debug/change your code to run correctly in parallel (as I myself did just for the heck of it - *i'll try to provide the code if anyone is interested, which I doubt*), the outcome will be that parallel execution of this code doesn't give you much advantage. The reason to my mind is as follows:

Imagine when `solver` iterates over 9 possible cell values it creates 9 branches of execution. If you create 2 threads using OpenMP, it will distribute top-level branches between threads in some way, say 5 branches executed by one thread and 4 by another, and in each thread branches will be executed consecutively, one by one. If initial sudoku state is valid, only one branch will lead to correct solution. Other branches will be cut short when they'll encounter discrepancy in the solution, so some will take longer and some will take shorter time to run, while the branch leading to correct solution will run the longest. You cannot predict what branches will take what time to execute, so there is no way to reasonably balance the workload among the threads. Even if you use OpenMP dynamic scheduling, chances are that while one thread executes the longest branch, other thread(s) will already finish all other branches and will wait for the last branch, because there are too little branches (so dynamic scheduling will be of little help).

Since creating threads and synchronizing data between them incurs some substantial overhead (compared to sequential `solver` running time of 0.01-10 ms), you'll see parallel execution time somewhat longer or shorter than sequential, depending on an input.

In any case, if the sequential solver running time is under 10 ms, why do you want to make it parallel?

Comment: Recursive threads doubling will only happen if he explicitly enables nested parallelism as it is disabled by default.

Comment: yes, the function is not complete, there are still several lines after the if(flags) function

Comment: I guess, there you clear the cell if the solution was not found, thus creating more confusion. So one thread might clear the cell, while another still thinks it works with its own version of the board.

Comment: Also, did you try testing this version with num_threads(1)? After you set flag=TRUE, you don't exit loop immediately, but continue to execute `if (checkExist(row, col, i)) outBoard[row][col] = i;`

Comment: @VictorKuznetsov, Yes, it works with **num_threads(1)** ,i also eliminated the **#pragma omp parallel for** as what Histro said, the duration is double of the **num_threads(2)** as usual =)...so it means my program is OK now!? i am quite sad of my coding skill now.

Comment: `num_threads(1)` is just to check that there are no bugs unrelated to parallel execution. `#pragma omp parallel` creates a number of working threads, and `#pragma omp for` will divide the following loop between the created threads. These pragmas can be joined into one `#pragma omp parallel for`.

Comment: If you have two nested `#pragma omp parallel (something)`, it's something else, because you create one parallel region within another, i.e. you try to run more parallel threads within already running parallel threads (but as Hristo noted, it does not happen if nesting is disabled). In fact, in your code the loop will be executed twice.

Comment: @VictorKuznetsov, thanks for your advice, i already clear the `#pragma omp parallel for` and just put `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2){for(i=1;i>10;i++)blablabla...}`  it works well, but i don't think it is a good coding practices =( anyway,Thanks =)

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)` without `#pragma omp for` will just execute the code in parallel region twice, but since variable `i` is shared between threads, loops will behave strangely because they will increment the same iterator. `#pragma omp for` on the other hand will keep separate iterators for different threads and the loop will be correctly separated between threads into equal parts. I suggest you to make a simple test program with just pragmas, single loop and output, and see for yourself.